# How to read a binary file of double numbers using Java?

Tags: java

I have a small application that is designed to get double numbers and store them into a binary file.  Then read them all again one by one and store them into an array,  but I can not figure out how to read the file properly?

Here is the code:

```
     import java.awt.*;
     import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
     import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
     import java.io.*;
     import java.util.ArrayList;

     import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

     import javax.swing.*;


  public class Q3 extends JFrame {

private JPanel thePanel;
private JLabel lblDouble;
private JTextField txtDouble;
private JButton btnAdd, btnStore, btnRead;

ArrayList<Double> doubleNumberArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList readArr = new ArrayList();
int index = 0;
int index2 = 0;

String fileName = "data.dat";

FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
DataOutputStream dOut = null;

FileInputStream fileIn = null;
DataInputStream dIn = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Q3();


}

public Q3() {

    this.setSize(250, 150);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    Color myColor = new Color(54, 139, 255);

    thePanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
    thePanel.setBackground(myColor);

    lblDouble = new JLabel("Enter a Double ");
    // Text Field
    txtDouble = new JTextField(5);
    // Buttons
    btnAdd = new JButton("Add");

    btnStore = new JButton("Store");

    btnRead = new JButton("Read File");

    ListenerForButton lForAddButton = new ListenerForButton();
    // Adding action listener to buttons
    btnAdd.addActionListener(lForAddButton);
    btnStore.addActionListener(lForAddButton);
    btnRead.addActionListener(lForAddButton);

    thePanel.add(lblDouble);
    thePanel.add(txtDouble, "wrap");
    thePanel.add(btnAdd, "skip1,split2");
    thePanel.add(btnStore, "wrap");
    thePanel.add(btnRead, "skip1");


    this.add(thePanel);
    this.setVisible(true);

}

// Implement Listener

public class ListenerForButton implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == btnAdd) {

            double convertDouble = Double.parseDouble(txtDouble.getText());
            doubleNumberArray.add(index, convertDouble);
            index++;
            txtDouble.setText("");

            System.out.print(doubleNumberArray);

        } else if (e.getSource() == btnStore) {

            for (int i = 0; i < doubleNumberArray.size(); i++) {

                try {

                    fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

                    dOut = new DataOutputStream(fileOut);

                    dOut.writeDouble(doubleNumberArray.get(i));


                } catch (Exception ex) {

                    ex.printStackTrace();

                } finally {
                    try {
                        dOut.close();


                    } catch (IOException e1) {

                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } // end of loop

            //System.out.println("Done");
            doubleNumberArray.clear();// empty our array
            index = 0;

        } else if (e.getSource() == btnRead) {

            try {

                fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                dIn = new DataInputStream(fileIn);

                System.out.println("Din" + dIn.available());

                try {

                    double d ;

                    while (dIn.available() > 0) {

                        d =  dIn.readDouble();
                        readArr.add(d);



                    }

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.print(readArr);

        }


    }// end of read button

}// action performed
```

}// end of listener

Comment: I am glad this has been resolved. Don't forget to accept the answer, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Use [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and [DataOutStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) if you want to read and write the primitive types respectively. [This example](http://www.java-examples.com/read-double-file-using-datainputstream) will get you started.

Sample to read until end of file. Notice that DataStreams detects an end-of-file condition by catching EOFException, instead of testing for an invalid return value. All implementations of DataInput methods use EOFException instead of return values.

```
public class Q3 extends JFrame
{
    private final JPanel thePanel;
    private final JLabel lblDouble;
    private final JTextField txtDouble;
    private final JButton btnAdd, btnStore, btnRead;

    private final List<Double> doubleNumberArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private final List<Double> readArr = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private int index = 0;

    private final String fileName = "c:/home/data.dat";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    new Q3();
    }

    public Q3()
    {
    this.setSize(250, 150);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    Color myColor = new Color(54, 139, 255);

    thePanel = new JPanel();
    thePanel.setBackground(myColor);

    lblDouble = new JLabel("Enter a Double ");
    // Text Field
    txtDouble = new JTextField(5);
    // Buttons
    btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
    btnStore = new JButton("Store");
    btnRead = new JButton("Read File");

    // Adding action listener to buttons
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ListenerForButton());
    btnStore.addActionListener(new StoreButtonListener());
    btnRead.addActionListener(new ReadButtonListener());

    thePanel.add(lblDouble);
    thePanel.add(txtDouble, "wrap");
    thePanel.add(btnAdd, "skip1,split2");
    thePanel.add(btnStore, "wrap");
    thePanel.add(btnRead, "skip1");

    this.add(thePanel);
    this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class ReadButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        DataInputStream din = null;
        try
        {
        din = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        readArr.clear();

        while (true)
        {
            Double data = din.readDouble();
            System.out.printf("\n-> %s \n ", data);
            readArr.add(data);
        }
        }
        catch (EOFException ignore)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ioe)
        {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
        if (din != null)
        {
            try
            {
            din.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }

    public class StoreButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        DataOutputStream outFile = null;
        try
        {
        outFile = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));

        for (int i = 0; i < doubleNumberArray.size(); i++)
        {
            Double d = doubleNumberArray.get(i);
            System.out.printf("\nWriting to file %s", d);
            outFile.writeDouble(d);
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
        if (outFile != null)
        {
            try
            {
            outFile.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
        doubleNumberArray.clear();// empty our array
        index = 0;
    }
    }

    public class ListenerForButton implements ActionListener
    {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        double convertDouble = Double.parseDouble(txtDouble.getText());
        doubleNumberArray.add(index, convertDouble);
        index++;
        txtDouble.setText("");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: sir, `in.available() > 0` is better than catching an exception.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi available() doesn't work with DataInputStream. I suggest you read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html

Comment: @cybersix whats the exception

Comment: too long to post in here :D

Comment: @cybersix, you are getting exception because you may not have written your file using `DataOutputStream` class.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi , you put that in a while loop cause i need to also add that into the array

Comment: @cybersix, how have you written your binary file ? using what class ?

Comment: @RaviTrivedi ,i am the one who posted this question and i did change everything to DataOutputStream the problem is now that i need a way to add the read double one by one to my array this is what i did but it only adds the first double   while(dIn.available()>0){


                            double d = dIn.readDouble();
                            readArr.add(index2,d);
                            index2++;

                        }

Comment: @cybersix, I know you posted this Q. I am telling you to re-post your updated code where you use `DataOutputStream`.

Comment: @CYBERSIX Added the working code to my post. also refactored some code.

Comment: All methods of DataInput throw EOFException at end of stream except readLine(), which returns a null.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DataInputStream` to read from file and `DataOutputStream` to write to file.

**Why `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` ?**

Because these classes support `Reading` and `Writing` in *modified* `UTF-8`.

**What is *modified* `UTF-8` ?**

*Modified* `UTF-8` means **Data** will be read and written in the form of `Java Primitive Types`. so that you can `read / write` straight your ***java variables*** in the file.

**Writing:**

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("MyBinaryFile.txt"));
out.writeDouble(double d);
```

**Reading:**

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("MyBinaryFile.txt"));
while(in.available() > 0)
{
in.readDouble();
}
```

**Note:** Make sure you `Read` and `Write` using same ***stream*** classes.

**Answer Updated:**

**1)** Take out these 2 lines out of `for` loop.

```
fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
dOut = new DataOutputStream(fileOut);
```

**2)** Also check how many elements exist in `doubleNumberArray` before writing to file.

**3)** Take this line `double d` out of while loop. Define `d` outside while loop and then use `d = dIn.readDouble()`.

**4)** Use `readArr.add(d)` instead of `readArr.add(index2,d)`. Because `ArrayList` creates indexes on its own as you require.