# How can I transport double values between python and java?

Tags: java, python

I want to save a numpy array lossless, so I can get it with a java program. (There are double values stored in the array.) What format can I use to transport the data?
So far, I have tried to transport the values as text, but that does not work well...

Comment: [`numpy.ndarray.tobytes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) might be of use, although you will need a way to export the shape info as well.

Comment: I can still transport the shape info as text. But how can I read the byte array into java and convert it back to an array?

Comment: [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16620233/8204776). Might be a good idea to design a custom binary header format which includes the shape info

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it.